# Multi-Network without plugin

Tags: multisite

Looking for a way to enable the Multi-Network feature without the [WP Multi Network plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-multi-network/). Essentially, I'm running into some errors with it where my subsites can't be accessed, so I wanted to see if there was an alternative way to enable the feature.

Comment: Check this link this may help you: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/network-of-multisite-networks/

Comment: I did follow through this tutorial when I installed the plugin. Unfortunately, all my subsites in any network besides my main network produce a 404 for the dashboard and the site itself.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for inconvenience caused and you are looking for multi network feature without plugin so you need to do some stuff on code to access sub sites:

// Multisite
define( 'MULTISITE',           true                  );

define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL',   false                 );

define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE',   '/'                   );

define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

// Likely not needed anymore (your config may vary)
//define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

//define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );

// Uncomment and change to a URL to funnel no-site-found requests to
//define( 'NOBLOGREDIRECT', '/404/' );

/**
 * These are purposely set for maximum compliance with multisite and
 * multinetwork. Your config may vary.

*/
define( 'WP_HOME',    'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );

For maximum flexibility, use something like this above

Comment: That is for setting up a multisite, what I'm looking for is a way to setup multiple networks under one site, like the plugin I mentioned does

Comment: Again, this is for a multisite setup as opposed to a multi-network. [MultiNetwork](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/)